# Step Definition detection only works when project is configured as cucumber project.- Virtual Machine

Tags: testing, automation

feature file and stepdefiniton file could not be connected.  It happens only in eclipse installed in Win Server 2012R2 Virtual Machine.

Answer (score 12):

This error will appear when you import any new cucumber project from git or directly from local system. Because you have not configured the project to cucumber and it is configured only to maven.

This error can appear for both Selenium and appium testing for web and mobile automation testing.

You can use below screenshot to convert to cucumber project.

[image: Right click on project- Click on Configure amd select configure as Cucumber project]

Comment: After i have done this. , Still didn't work for me.

Comment: @Saikat Update the cucumber version and check again

Answer (score 4):

This issue will be resolved if you convert the project as a cucumber project.
Right-click on your project from the *Project Explorer* > *Configure* > *Convert as Cucumber Project*.

Comment: While this is true, the question is why do this? Step definition detection used to work before without having to do this. In fact, in my team, there's a member who has a Java/Maven project and detection works fine. Mine used to work before and then stopped working out of the sudden.

Comment: this setting is required when you are using the latest version of eclipse and remembers this setting is required only when you import your project in eclipse. If you use any other tools like IntelliJ, Netbeans then this configurations will not be required.

Comment: I am using Eclipse 2018-12 and I didn't need that configuration until very recent. Something else might've changed. Again, a member of my team hasn't done this configuration and his workspace links glue code just fine. There's got to be another explanation.

Answer (score -1):

After changing the project to Cucumber the issue resolved for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).